# How to show a specific div base user data in java script with my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Problem resolvedby me**
resolve way :i user ko.js for check bining data in java to resolve my problem! thanks to all

I have this code to show my online users in my chat script (x7chat 3, you can [download it free](http://x7chat.com))

This code is in this file in the script:
x7chatDIR\templates\default\pages\chat.php

```
<div id="onlinelist" data-bind="foreach: active_room().users()">
    <div class="onlineuser" data-bind="click: $root.show_user_profile"><a href='#' data-bind="text: user_name"></a><br></div>
</div>
```

I want to check a var if that var was 'admin' show this div :

```
<div class="onlineuser" data-bind="click: $root.show_user_profile"><a href='#' data-bind="text: user_name"></a><br></div>
```

and else show this:

```
<div class="onlineuser2" data-bind="click: $root.show_user_profile"><a href='#' data-bind="text: user_name"></a><br></div>
```

In really I want show admin in div that it's class is "onlineuser2" I want show admin id in another color from users!

sorry for my english.... eng is not my native language!

Comment: does `text: user_name` assumes `string` `"admin"` value?

Comment: please clarify more how do you want to handle this situation, you're goal is ambiguos now.

Comment: it is clear! i want if     user_name == admin  then show user in div that have useronline2 class

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you want this..

try this

```
var yourVar="admin";
if(yourVar=="admin"){
    $('.onlineuser2').hide();
    $('.onlineuser').show();
}else{
   $('.onlineuser').hide()
   $('.onlineuser2').show();
}
```

Comment: this show me 2 div ! i want show the onlineuser div for admin user , example with a *mark side of it's username

Answer (score 0):

test this

```
  if(admin == true) {
     $(".onlineuser2").hide();
     $(".onlineuser").show();
  }
  else {
     $(".onlineuser").hide();
     $(".onlineuser2").show();  
  }
```

Comment: what contains the admin var?

Comment: data-bind="text: user_name"   see the code i post! this code is a loop that load users in a room... an show them in a div ... i want if user == admin  .... show it a diffrent div  and if user is a normal user show in normal div

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this:

```
$("[data-bind='text: admin']").parent()
                              .removeClass('.onlineuser')
                              .addClass('.onlineuser2');
```

Comment: you can place it inside your scripting file